# upload file from client android to sever django

Tags: android, django, file-upload

I'm trying to upload my file not only image file but any file from android to django directory I specified. I tried some methods in online, but failed. Any advice is welcome.

**faced problem:**
After Android code execution, django log returns code 200 without error code. But what's strange is that a response message that I never intended is returned. I think the response message should be "success," but the "OK" message is returned and nothing is stored. The actual transferred byte on the long log is 0 bytes.

My Reference
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/

**=====Android Files=====**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView contentView2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contentView2=findViewById(R.id.content2);

        HashMap<String, String> recordMap=new HashMap<>();
        recordMap.put("name","GetUserFile");
        RecordSender recordSender = new RecordSender();
        recordSender.request("http://my_server_ip_address/recommender/GetUserFile/".concat("100"), recordMap, httpCallbackSend,"/data/data/com.example.servertest/databases/recommend.jpg");
    }

    HttpCallback httpCallbackSend=new HttpCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(String result) {
            try{
                contentView2.setText(result);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**RecordSender.java**

```
public class RecordSender {
    private static final String TAG = "RECORDSENDER";
    RecordTask http;

    public void request(String url, HashMap<String, String> param, HttpCallback callback, String filePath) {
        http = new RecordTask(url, param, callback, filePath);
        http.execute();
    }

    private class RecordTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String url;
        HashMap<String, String> param;
        HttpCallback callback;
        String filePath;

        public RecordTask(String url, HashMap<String, String> param, HttpCallback callback, String filePath) {
            this.url = url;
            this.param = param;
            this.callback = callback;
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                URL text = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) text.openConnection();
                http.setRequestProperty("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
                http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;");
                http.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                http.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                http.setReadTimeout(10000);
                http.setRequestMethod("POST");
                http.setDoInput(true);
                http.setDoOutput(true);
                http.setUseCaches(false);
                http.connect();

                File file = new File(filePath);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                DataOutputStream request = new DataOutputStream(http.getOutputStream());

                //long fileSize = file.length();
                //long totalReadBytes = 0;
                int readBytes;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while ((readBytes = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) 
                    request.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                   
                request.flush();

                String resp =  http.getResponseMessage();
                return resp;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            this.callback.onResult(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**=====Django Files=====**

**forms.py**
from django import forms

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for django_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'tm84)gy^7db*rb$k*h@4nokmgkqrqq(q*h&f06lzni_#=e8e6&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'recommender',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
 #   'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
#    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 10240
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('GetUserFile/<str:ID>', views.GetUserFile, name='GetUserFile')
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import FileResponse
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
import mimetypes
from shutil import copy

# Create your views here.
from .forms import UploadFileForm
from django.conf import settings

def GetUserFile(request, ID):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES, ID)
            return HttpResponse("success")
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})


def handle_uploaded_file(file, ID):
    dirpath = './recommender/userprofile/'+ID #specified file path
    if not (os.path.isdir(dirpath)):
        os.mkdir(dirpath)

    with open('./recommender/userprofile/'+ID+'/filename', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Well... What is the priblem/error/exception? Your Android code looks ok.

Comment: After Android code execution, django log returns code 200 without error code. But what's strange is that a response message that I never intended is returned. I think the response message should be "success," but the "OK" message is returned and nothing is stored. The actual transferred byte on the long log is 0 bytes.